# Random loss of SSH connection between virtual and physical computer

Tags: ssh, vmware-workstation

I work on a problem that has been bugging me for some days now, and I don't know where to go next. I got a Windows 7 computer with VMware workstation on, and in VMware I have an Ubuntu 10.04 server running.
My problem is when I connect to the server from windows, using Putty, it throws the connection after a random period of time. 
It only happens when I connect from the windows, not if I connect from another computer. (I tried both with Linux console SSH, and putty from other windows’, and computers with same network driver as my)

But the problem gets even more random. When I run a tcpdump on the server, it doesn’t happen, or if other computers are connected, but when I closes tcpdump, or the other connections, it throws the connection between physical and virtual computer, after some time.

Lastly it’s a converted vmdk, I am running on the VMware workstation, but I’ve tried it on other computers without problems.

Answer (score 0):

Checkout PuTTY's "Enable TCP keepalives" option (see "Connection" during PuTTY configuration). That did the trick for me once.

Comment: No I did do that, and it didn't help. Otherwise it should have been the same for the other computers!

I'm not a total noob ;-)